# Is there a way to name a tensorflow variable based on the value of another tensor-variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to be able to do the following

```
n = str(tf.constant(2))
v = tf.get_variable(name=n, shape=(256,256), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

but doing this is converts n to a string representation of tensorflow variable i.e

```
"<tf.Tensor 'Const_4:0' shape=() dtype=int32>"
```

Comment: You can get name like this: `n = tf.constant(2).name`

Comment: Or `tf.constant(2).op.name`, to avoid getting the extra `:0` at the end.